# How filter two specific values in one column that has a common value in another column

Tags: python, pandas

### Question

The minimum reproducible example of my data frame looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'patient': ['patient1', 'patient1', 'patient1','patient2', 'patient2', 'patient3','patient3','patient4','patient4','patient4','patient4'], 
                   'gene':['TYR','TYR','TYR','TYR','TYR','TYR','TYR','TYR','TYR', 'TYR','TYR'],
                   'variant': ['buu', 'luu', 'stm','lol', 'bla', 'buu', 'lol','buu', 'luu', 'IDK','ploy'],
                    'genotype': ['hom', 'het', 'hom','het', 'hom', 'het', 'het','het', 'hom', 'hom','hom']})

df

 patient gene variant genotype
0   patient1  TYR     buu      hom
1   patient1  TYR     luu      het
2   patient1  TYR     stm      hom
3   patient2  TYR     lol      het
4   patient2  TYR     bla      hom
5   patient3  TYR     buu      het
6   patient3  TYR     lol      het
7   patient4  TYR     ploy     het
8   patient4  TYR     luu      hom
9   patient4  TYR     IDK      hom
10  patient4  TYR     buu      hom
```

I need to identify patients with the variants "buu" and "luu"

### Results

```
patient1  TYR     buu      hom
patient1  TYR     luu      het
patient4  TYR     luu      hom
patient4  TYR     buu      hom
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['variant'].isin(['buu','luu'])]`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your command returns also patient who has one of the two variants only. For example your command return patient1 and patient4 but also patient3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group by `patient` and filter groups keeping those whose `variant` contains both required variants (`buu`, `luu`):

```
var_set = {'buu', 'luu'}  # set of variants
df[df['variant'].isin(var_set)].groupby('patient')\
    .filter(lambda x: set(x['variant']) >= var_set)
```

---

- `set(A) >= set(B)` gives `True` when set `A` is a superset of set `B`

Since the dataset is filtered from the start (by `var_set`) the same effect can be achieved with the following group filters:

- `set(x['variant']) == var_set`
- `x['variant'].nunique() == 2`

---

```
    patient gene variant genotype
0  patient1  TYR     buu      hom
1  patient1  TYR     luu      het
7  patient4  TYR     buu      het
8  patient4  TYR     luu      hom
```

Comment: if you query `isin(var_set)` then you can just filter with `==`. You can also filter with `nunique()==2`

Comment: @QuangHoang, you're right, I've added those as alternatives to the answer

Answer (score 1):

another method would be to first filter your dataframe and then use `.nunique` with `.transform` to find the rows that match your condition.

```
df1 = df.loc[df["variant"].isin(["buu", "luu"])]

out = df1.loc[
        df1.groupby(["patient", df1["variant"].isin(["luu", "buu"])])["variant"].transform(
            "nunique"
        )
        >= 2
    ]

print(out)

    patient gene variant genotype
0  patient1  TYR     buu      hom
1  patient1  TYR     luu      het
7  patient4  TYR     buu      het
8  patient4  TYR     luu      hom
```